# How to decode a json from api in php (multidimensional array)

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want to decode json code with php in wordpress.

this is my code. but did not work.

```php
function decode_func(){
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city=jakarta');
    $decoded_json = json_decode($json,true);
    $results = $decoded_json['results'];

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $datetime = $result['datetime'];
        foreach($datetime as $datetim) {
            $times = $datetim['times'];
            foreach($times as $time) {
                echo $time['Sunrise'];
            }
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('decode','decode_func');
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: @mrodo.  Nothing can be returned. The output is empty! No error is displayed.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  Did the shortcode run?  There is a typo in "$times = datetim['times']", the last "e" is missing from $datetime.

Comment: `$decoded_json` works fine and returns a valid multidimensional array on my end. Which of those arrays are you interested in?

Comment: @Ruvee times and date array.

Comment: @Dave S If I did not call the shortcode, then how can I expect it to work?!

Comment: @Tadbir Perhaps you could start debugging by looking at just the JSON decoding and printing, and leave the wordpress "wrap" out for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and what I found out is that your property targeting is incorrect.

In order to get the `Sunrise` property by foreach loops alone and not directly targeting that property you need to do the following.

```php
$json         = file_get_contents('https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city=jakarta');
$decoded_json = json_decode($json,true);
$results      = $decoded_json['results'];

foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    if ($key !== 'datetime') continue;

    foreach($result as $datetime) {
        foreach ($datetime as $time) {
            if (!empty($time['Sunrise'])) echo $time['Sunrise'];
        }
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

In order to get the city as well I created a new if condition with a elseif.
The code is almost the same, because location is not a multi dimentional array its less foreachs to get the city value

```php
$json         = file_get_contents('https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city=jakarta');
$decoded_json = json_decode($json,true);
$results      = $decoded_json['results'];

foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    if ($key === 'datetime') {
        foreach($result as $datetime) {
            foreach ($datetime as $time) {
                if (!empty($time['Sunrise'])) echo $time['Sunrise'];
            }
        }
    } else if ($key === 'location') {
        if (!empty($result['city'])) echo $result['city'];
    }
}
```

Comment: very thank's. work fine. can you help me how can in get "city" name in "location" array? thank.

Comment: @Tadbir Updated my answer to include the city as well

Comment: thanks' man. Greate